# How to make any two check boxes or Radio mandatory out of six in DocuSign Template

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement wherein user should at least fill/select any two options to sign the form. As per my understanding this is not possible with current check box and Radio tags. Is there any hack / workaround which will allow me to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to achieve this through the form validation features that DocuSign provides. If your signer is an embedded/captive recipient (i.e., is accessing the envelope via your website), then you could build a webpage to collect the data from the signer (and validate the data per your requirements), and then pass the data into the DocuSign documents via the "Create Envelope" API call.